# It is possible to ignore fields if it doesn't exists in document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    // ....
    conditions: {},
    // ....
});
```

Conditions - nested document and I can save anything into it with any key. And let's say we have such conditions:

```
{
    "conditions": {
        "age": 10,
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

This is located on the base. Now, I want to find this document, but since I don't know what fields are there, I am facing problems...

```
const conditions = {
    'conditions.age': 10,
    'conditions.name': 'John',
    'conditions.surname': 'White' // surname doesn't exists
}
const result = await Model.find(conditions);
console.log(result) // [];
```

And the question is, is it possible to exclude from the filter the fields that are missing in the document? So that find() simply skipped them, did not take them into account...

Comment: Do you want to find only those documents that only has age = 10 and name = John, but doesn't contain no other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Logical Query Operators* `$and` and `$or` as below-

```
const conditions = {
  $and: [
    { 'conditions.age': 10, },
    { 'conditions.name': 'John', },
    { $or: [{ 'conditions.surname': { $exists: false } }, { 'conditions.surname': 'White' }] }
  ]
}
const result = await Model.find(conditions);
```